# How to FFT a sound array correctly?

Tags: c++, fftw, libsndfile

I am trying to get a list of frequencies present in an input audio sample. It seems I need to do an FFT to get this result, but I get odd answers when I FFT it (using FFTW): I get arrays containing mostly zeros with a few impossibly large elements (300+ digits!) - and these large numbers are always in the same place (5 places from the end, 46 places from the end and a few others that show up sporadically) whether I change the frequency of the input tone or even if I change the sample length for the FFT. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>    

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
    char        *infilename ;
    SNDFILE     *infile = NULL ;
    FILE        *outfile = NULL ;
    SF_INFO     sfinfo ;

    infile = sf_open("test.wav", SFM_READ, &sfinfo);

    int N = pow(2, 10);
    double samples[N];

    sf_read_double(infile, samples, 1);

    fftw_complex out[N];
    fftw_plan p;
    p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, samples, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p); 

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("%f %f\n", out[i][0], out[i][1]);
    }

    sf_close (infile) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your input data (i.e. `samples`) is sane?

Comment: It's a wav file, and other media players play it normally. Does that make it sane?

Comment: I'm sure the file is valid, but have you confirmed that you've read it in correctly?  As in, if you print the values of `samples`, do they look reasonable?

Comment: Actually, no they don't. Mostly `0.000000` with a few actual numbers in there. Am I doing something wrong with how I use libsndfile?

Comment: I've never used this library before, so I'm afraid I have no specific advice on that.  But a quick look at the documentation (http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#open) reveals the following: "When opening a file for read, the format field should be set to zero before calling sf_open()".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Thanks! That led me to my actual problem: I needed to change `sf_read_double(infile, samples, 1)` to `sf_read_double(infile, samples, N)`. This now produces sane-looking values for the WAV data. Unfortunately, I still don't get logical output from the FFT - or at least, I'm still always getting big values in bins 5 and 46, although there's now values in a few other bins.

Comment: You might want to experiment with a known signal first. I.e. initialize `samples[N]` to `A sin (B*i)`

Comment: I changed it to use a sine wave, initializing `samples[i]` to `sin(i*0.01)`. The result had a whole bunch of bins filled: bins 0,1,2,526,527,543,544,551,555, and a bunch more. I feel like I'm doing something wrong with the FFT.

Comment: Ok, if I square the real and imaginary components, add them together, and take the square root, I now get sane and logical values. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was twofold: firstly, I wasn't loading all the sound data, and secondly, I was just taking the real component of the result. Also, I was still getting the unusable part of the FFT (above the Nyquist frequency). Changing `sf_read_double(infile, samples, 1)` to `sf_read_double(infile, samples, N)`, changing `for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {` to `for (int i=0; i<N/2; i++) {` and changing

```
printf("%f %f\n", out[i][0], out[i][1]);
```

to

```
printf("%i %f\n", i*21, sqrt(out[i][0]*out[i][0] + out[i][1]*out[i][1]));
```

gave me the good results I wanted.